# Tableau Prep aggregation: unexpected output

Tags: tableau-api

When I did aggregation on Tableau Prep, I got unexpected output.
The data I contains date and Id field and I aggregated by date field.
Then count of ID of each date should be the output.

When I check the last step of the Prep flow, it looks ok.
However, when I export it as csv file, date value is blank and only has 12 rows.
It looks the output is aggregated by Month.

Here is the example of the data.

**Data on Tableau Prep:**

```
Count   Date
1000    10/28/2017
3400    11/13/2017
...
..
```

(Date has 407 unique values)

**Data on CSV:**

```
Count   Date
5000    (blank)
7000    (blank) 
...
..
```

(only 12 rows)

Comment: Http;//Tableau.com/support